# NumPy 64bit fail to install with pip on Windows with Python 64bit

Tags: numpy, 64-bit, pip

```
pip install "c:\temp\numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp35-cp35m-wi
n_amd64.whl"
```

returns the following error:

> **numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this pl atform.**

OS: Windows 7 pro 64bit
pip version: 8.1.0
Python: **3.5.1 64bit**

NumPy wheel file: numpy-1.10.4+mkl-**cp35**-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

So, all the version are aligned I think.
Or Python 3.5.1 is too new for cp35?

Note. On another PC with exactly the same versions but Windows 10 it works.

Thanks,
Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

I looked into req_install.py and wheel.py files of pip (in [python path]/lib/site-packages/pip) and I found where is done the check of the wheel.
It split the file name to obtain "tags" from it for comparison with supported tags.

I removed the environment variable "PLATFORM" (it is not present in the other machine) and then it worked.