# change python distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, intel-mkl

I've run into problems import `scipy.interpolate` module. It uses numpy. I am on windows 7 and have managed python and all the modules without a distribution manager like anaconda. Pip is easy to use so that's how I do it. But part of numpy on windows can, and maybe needs to, leverage intel math kernel library. 
My problem is along the lines of [Difference between Numpy and Numpy-MKL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513044/difference-between-numpy-and-numpy-mkl)

I've tried solutions described like this: [How to install numpy+mkl for python 2.7 on windows 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217793/how-to-install-numpymkl-for-python-2-7-on-windows-64-bit) Since I use python 3, and my processor is a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz, I've tried a few of the whl's on here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy . I can't seem to pick the right one because pip will say that whl is not supported on my platform.

So should I just switch to the Intel Distribution for Python? https://software.intel.com/en-us/distribution-for-python. Will switching to a distribution mess up my python directory structures?

I also found this solution: [NumPy 64bit fail to install with pip on Windows with Python 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935486/numpy-64bit-fail-to-install-with-pip-on-windows-with-python-64bit) but I'm not sure if editing pip itself should be necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem some time ago, and what worked for me in the end was to uninstall numpy and scipy, download the correct 64 bit wheel from [gohlke's webside](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and then rename the `*win64.whl` file to `*win32.whl`

For some reason when installing Numpy with MKL, pip was unable to detect the correct architecture.

**Before doing this**, I will recommend you to simply try to upgrade pip to the latest version (10.1), and try to install normally (this issue report looks related: https://bugs.python.org/issue18987).

It's also important to install Numpy+MKL **before** Scipy.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I figured it out- i have 32 bit python on my 64 bit machine. It works now. I didn't have to install numpy+mkl before Scipy, either. I didn't try any other distribution manager, such as the intel one, either.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have 32 bit python, not 64. Choosing the latest (1.15) numpy enabled it to install, and now scipy.interpolate loads and runs.